# Clash Of Heroes (iPhone): Completing Irollan

Tags: ios, clash-of-heroes

I've finished the main campaign in Clash of Heroes (iPhone version) and am now tidying up the side quests.  On the Irollan world map there was a stat saying "8/12"

I did everything U could find in Irollan (puzzles and bounty fights), and when I went back to the bounty hunter to get the last reward I got a popup saying "All side quests completed" or words to that effect.

But, when I go back to the world map, Irollan has the completion stat saying "11/12".  So, my question is - what else do I need to do to get up to 12/12?  Is there anything *besides* side quests that gets this stat up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am fairly certain that the 12 is a bug in the iOS version.  See this screenshot from my Steam copy of the game, which indicates that there are 11 tasks in Irollan.

[image: Screenshot Showing 11/11 on Irollan]

Comment: Oh, interesting.  The i{Phone version seems to have lots of bugs, for example not even being able to see the right hand number in the completed tasks summary, in most cases, due to it having some graphic on top of it.  I think it's quite a rushed and buggy conversion.